# How to Implement Login/ PHP Web App within Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web, web-applications

I've included a manual php file inside the template folder of wordpress. 
Then created a page of its type in wordpress. 
Then the user interface related to the specific php file will be displayed. 
It contains a simple login functionality. 
When the username and password is matched, it should redirect to the next php welcome page. Instead it reloads itself. 
How to load the next php file to this page ?

```
    <?php

   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

   $sql = "SELECT varEmail FROM tblUser WHERE varEmail = '$myusername' and varPassword = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


      $error = "Inside";
      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
     wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 302 );//exit; 

       $error = "{$myusername}{':'}{$mypassword }"; 
      }else {
       $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>

<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Online Survey
    */
    get_header();
    ?>
    <?php
    $page_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'iweb_page_title', TRUE); 
    $mb_portfolio = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'iweb_page_portfolio', TRUE);
    $mb_signup = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'iweb_page_signup', TRUE); 
    $mb_clients = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'iweb_page_clients', TRUE); 
    ?>
    <!-- PAGE TITLE -->
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <div class="page-title-container clearfix">
                <?php if ($page_title != '') { ?>
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs'); ?> 
                <?php } ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>  <!-- Grey bg end -->
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="m-bot-10">
            <?php if(iwebtheme_smof_data('map_enable') != 0) { ?>
                    <!-- Google Maps -->
                        <section class="google-map-container">
                            <div id="googlemaps" class="google-map"></div>
                        </section>
                    <!-- Google Maps / End -->
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>


    <!-- CONTACT FORM-->
    <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="ten columns  m-bot-35">


                    <form action = "" method = "post">
                      <label>Email  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                      <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                      <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
                   </form>

                   <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
            </div>




    </div>  
    <?php if($mb_portfolio != 'Disable') { ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/part-portfolio' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($mb_signup != 'Disable') { ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/part-newsletter' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($mb_clients != 'Disable') { ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'includes/part-clients' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

How can I load the welcoome.php file ?

```
 wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 302 );//exit;
```

It's hosted shared. Is it possible to create a php web application alongside wordpress , and call that application inside php or redirect a php page to the web application ?

Login is successful, but I cannot load the other pages. Or should I load them dynamically ?

Comment: you need exit after wp_redirect also no code will run after this so your error variable will not be set. I dont see how you are logging in, you are probably getting 1 row from the db but thats not the same as logging in. You can redirect, just make sure there is no output before the redirect. Also your code above will be quite easy to brute force a login :(

Comment: Yes. it doesn't work. I used a separate codeigniter project instead.